# What transition should I use between a room and a stairway with a door?

Tags: hardwood-floor, transition

[image]I have two rooms plus a bathroom above my garage. There is a stairway in the back of the garage that leads to it. There is a door at the top of the stairway that leads to this space. I installed tongue and groove wood flooring throughout both rooms in the space. The floor boards are perpendicular to the stairway door. I need a "transition" of some type. Some people have told me I should use a "step down" transition and others have said to use a "stairnose". WHat type of transition should I use? The boards are hickory wood. It's Bruce's hickory country natural. It's 3 1/4" width boards that are 3/4" thick.

Comment: What you _should_ use is whatever makes the transition from one material/level to the other to your satisfaction. It's entirely up to you, which is why opinion-based questions like this are off-topic. If you want a fact-based answer, at a minimum, you should tell us the difference in heights between the different floor levels. It's entirely possible to install 3/4" flooring perfectly flush with the next floor surface, above it or even below it and we don't know what you have.

Comment: A picture would be wonderful...

Comment: Pic on the way. The flooring is 3/4" and it needs to step down that entire height.

Comment: I think this is what I probably need. https://www.walmart.com/ip/Oak-Overlap-for-3-4-Material-Transition-Strip-3-1-2-Wide-W-1248-U-6-FT/794470522

Comment: Seems like a textbook scenario for  a stair nosing. Why isn't that your default solution?

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that.